# Where do I find \futurelet's nasty behaviour documented?

Tags: tex-core

Until recently, I thought that execution of

```
\futurelet\testtoken<token1><token2>...
```

has the following effect: The control sequence `\testtoken` is `\let` to `<token2>` and `\futurelet\testtoken` is stripped from the input stream, so TeX continues with `<token1><token2>...`.

In [this answer of mine](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/9035/how-to-pass-an-optional-argument-to-an-environment-with-verbatim-content/9187#9187) I observed (with TH's help) that this is not quite true with respect to catcodes, and in [this nice answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/9897/all-those-braces-implicit-explicit-iffalse-fi-etc/10371#10371) Philippe explains that things can also go terribly wrong in nested alignments. For the sake of completeness let me give two short examples here.

```
\def\activateA{\catcode`A=\active}
{\activateA
 \gdefA{undocumented behaviour?}
}
An \futurelet\testtoken\activateA A
\bye
```

The expected output is "An undocumented behaviour?", but this one gets only when `\futurelet\testtoken` is removed. With the `\futurelet`, the output is just "An A". The reason seems to be that `\futurelet` fixes the catcode of the last `A`. (One still gets that `\testtoken=the letter A`.)

The second example is a bit longer and more involved.

```
\def\begintestalign{\show\testtoken
    $\vcenter\bgroup\halign\bgroup##&##\cr}
\def\endtestalign{\egroup\egroup$}
\halign{#&#\cr
a & \futurelet\testtoken
    \begintestalign
         & c  \cr
    test & de \cr
    \endtestalign \cr
}
\bye
```

The expected output is [image] (and one would expect `\testtoken=alignment tab character &`), but instead one gets `\testtoken=\outer endtemplate`, and then

```
! Emergency stop.
<recently read> \endtemplate 

<template> \endtemplate 

l.7          &
               c  \cr
!  ==> Fatal error occurred, no output PDF file produced!
```

I can't fully understand what's happening here, but my main question is: Where do I find this behaviour of `\futurelet` documented?

(And honestly, I'd really like to have a `\futurelet` that behaves as expected; the implemented behaviour is rather mean, and I wonder if that's a bug or a feature.)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

There are actually two parts to your question that are interacting a bit strangely.

For the first example, the behavior is completely sensible. As others have observed, the `A` is tokenized and given category code 11. Once a character token is tokenized, it never loses its category code (except for e-TeX's `\detokenize` extension).

The second example is much trickier. My initial reaction was that it *should* work as you want. Unfortunately, TeX treats `\halign` in a very strange way. Let me quote from *The TeXbook*, page 248.

> You have to be careful with the use of `&` and `\span` and `\cr` because these tokens are intercepted by TeX's scanner even when it is not expanding macros. For example, if you say ‘`\let\x=\span`’ in the midst of an alignment entry, TeX will think that the ‘`\span`’ ends the entry so `\x` will become equal to the first token following the ‘`#`’ in the template. You can hide this `\span` by putting it in braces; e.g., ‘`{\global\let\x=\span}`’. (And Appendix D explains how to avoid `\global` here.)

This is very surprising, but it explains the behavior you see. Namely, when TeX encounters the `&` when looking for the token to `\let` to `\testtoken`, it sees a `&` and so inserts the rest of the template (empty in this case) followed by `\endtemplate`—the command that causes the contents of the alignment entry to be typeset in an "unset" box (meaning the glue hasn't been set yet).

Comment: Thanks a lot! This is my top candidate for an accepted answer so far since you found a spot where it's actually _documented_.

Comment: Maybe a bit of advertisement is allowed here: Consider upvoting not only this, but also the other answers that explain a lot of the mystery. In particular Bruno's answer(s) is (are) seriously underrated!

Comment: I second Hendrik's comment. I missed one of those answers when I looked earlier. That has been corrected.

Answer (score 21):

IMHO the shown behavior in the first example is understandable, i.e. "correct". The TeXbook says about the `\futurelet` macro (p.207):

> TEX also allows the construction `\futurelet\cs<token1><token2>`, which has
>   the effect of `\let\cs = <token2><token1><token2>`.

So we are talking about *tokens*, which already have their catcode assigned. In your example `A` is the `<token2>` and must be read by TeX in order to assign it to the command sequence `\testtoken`. The macro `\activateA` is not executed yet so the catcode of A is still *letter*. When it is *placed back into the input stream*  (which is the main point here) the catcode change in `\activeA` doesn't effect it any longer.

So actually `\futurelet\cs<token1><token2>` does not have the 100% same effect of `\let\cs = <token2><token1><token2>` because in the second case `<token1>` can still modify the catcodes in effect for reading the second `<token2>`.

You second example is much more tricky. IMHO you are falling victim to automatically inserted code after (and before) the cell content. Therefore when `\futurelet` is executed there is really an `\outer endtemplate` behind it. This is then a behaviour of `\halign` and shouldn't be blamed on `\futurelet`. [As you know](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/11329/2975) my knowledge about `\halign` is still limited so I can't example the resulting error as well.

I would say if there is a documentation of this behaviour, it is in *The TeXbook*. I don't think eTeX changed the behavior of `\futurelet` in any way.

Comment: Thanks, I've learned one important lesson from your answer: `\futurelet` has to be fed 3 _tokens_ (the first of which has to be a control sequence), and so these tokens have to be formed and sent to TeX's stomach. (I hadn't thought of this!) And then the trouble can't be avoided anymore. Yes, the 2nd example is about automatically inserted code after the template; this was clear to me (hidden behind "can't _fully_ understand"), but probably not to others, so it's good you explained that. Maybe it's _implicitly_ explained in the TeXbook, but I didn't find an explicit explanation.

Comment: @Hendrik: Yes, "implicitly explained" was also something which came to my mind.

Answer (score 11):

**Disclaimer:** *I have no references to support my claims below.*

Let me start with a simple example:

```
\def\showtoken{\show\testtoken}
\halign{#b\cr
  a\futurelet\testtoken\showtoken\cr}
```

When it reads the first cell, TeX sees the unexpandable token `a`, so it knows that there is no `\omit`. It then inserts the part of the template before `#`, namely, nothing, and it prepares to insert the part of the template after `#`, namely, `b`, when the cell finishes.

It then reads the `\futurelet`, and executes it. Thus TeX looks for three tokens. The first and second are `\testtoken` and `\showtoken`. The third is *not* `\cr`: when it sees `\cr` in this context, TeX inserts what it desperately wants to insert: the end of the template, `b`. So we have `\futurelet \testtoken \showtoken b`. Then `\testtoken` is `\let` to `b`, and we are shown `b` by the macro `\showtoken`.

An interesting combination of `\futurelet` and `\afterassignment` allows you to peek two tokens ahead, and we check that `\futurelet` indeed reads the tokens `\testtoken`, `b` and `c` and assigns `\testtoken=c`.

```
\def\showtoken{\show\testtoken}
\halign{#bcd\cr
  a\afterassignment\showtoken\futurelet\testtoken\cr}
```

Now delete `cd` in the template. TeX should print on your terminal

```
> \testtoken=\outer endtemplate:
.
\showtoken ->\show \testtoken 

<to be read again> 
                   b
<to be read again> 
                   \endtemplate 
<template> b\endtemplate 

l.3 ...assignment\showtoken\futurelet\testtoken\cr
                                                  }
```

As you can see, the tokens inserted by TeX at the end of the cell are ended by `\endtemplate`, which is some internal token. Removing even the `b`, we see that `\futurelet` reads `\testtoken`, the internal `\endtemplate`, and the following token, `}`. Then TeX crashes.

A variant on this is to grab the `\endtemplate` using `\let`, and redo it to close the template. Playing around with the code below, I notice that if we put anything else than `\testtoken` (which holds the `\endtemplate`) in the last position of `\showdotoken`, TeX crashes. I have no idea why.

```
\def\showdotoken{\show\testtoken \testtoken}
\halign{#\cr
  a\afterassignment\showdotoken\let\testtoken\cr
}
```

It seems that TeX crashes whenever we try to reach out after the end of a cell in an alignment: both `\halign` below crash.

```
\halign{#\cr
  a\futurelet\testtoken\cr}
\halign{#&#\cr
  a\futurelet\testtoken & text\cr}
```

Back on Hendrik's example.

```
\def\begintestalign{\show\testtoken
    $\vcenter\bgroup\halign\bgroup##&##\cr}
\def\endtestalign{\egroup\egroup$}
\halign{#&#\cr
a & \futurelet\testtoken
    \begintestalign
         & c  \cr
    test & de \cr
    \endtestalign \cr
}
```

The `\futurelet` takes three tokens: `\testtoken`, `\begintestalign`, and the material that TeX is waiting to insert as soon as it sees either `&` or `\cr` (or `\crcr`), namely, nothing, followed by the internal `\endtemplate`. So that `&` is already converted to `\endtemplate` (and perhaps some `\begin-next-template`) of the first `\halign`. Then `\begintestalign` is read, creates a new inner `\halign`, and that `\halign` awaits a fresh `&`... it sees an old `&`, already belonging to the enclosing `\halign`.

All this might be related to an error mentioned in the TeXbook, p. 299:

> **Interwoven alignment preambles are not allowed.**
>
> If you have been so devious as to get this message, 
>   you will understand it, and you will deserve no sympathy.

Comment: Thanks for this analysis; I'll still have to think more about it. Combining `\futurelet` and `\afterassignment` is a great idea!

Answer (score 3):

`futurelet` deserved its own chapter in the TeXbook but perhaps Knuth underestimated its importance. Best article I came across so far is by Victor Eijkhout in the TUGboat [Macros with optional arguments](http://www.tug.org/TUGboat/Articles/tb22-1-2/tb70eijk.pdf)

Comment: Well, you're right indeed with your first sentence. However, Eijkhout doesn't seem to write anything about the nasty behaviour.

Answer (score 2):

I'm posting this fix as a separate answer, and as community wiki, in the hope that people can improve on it.

Since the second of Hendrik's problems happens when `\futurelet` reads `&` and triggers the end of the outside alignment cell, the idea is to make `&` an active character. Most of the time, we will `\let` it to an implicit alignment tab `\ampImplicit`. Just before using `\futurelet`, we change the definition of `&` to be something harmless, and we restore the usual definition after the `\futurelet` assignment.

The code below *typesets* what Hendrik expects, but the `\testtoken` is `\relax`, i.e. the safe control sequence that we defined `&` to be just before `\futurelet`. We could replace `\let&\relax` by `\def&{something recognizable}` if we care enough.

```
\let\ampImplicit&
\catcode`\&=13\relax
\let&\ampImplicit

\def\makeampImplicit{\iffalse{\fi \let&\ampImplicit \iffalse}\fi }
\def\safefuturelet{\relax
  \iffalse{\fi \let&\relax \iffalse}\fi 
  \afterassignment\makeampImplicit
  \futurelet
}

% Hendrik's code, with `\futurelet` replaced by `\safefuturelet`.

\def\begintestalign{\show\testtoken
    $\vcenter\bgroup\halign\bgroup##&##\cr}
\def\endtestalign{\egroup\egroup$}
\halign{#&#\cr
a & \safefuturelet\testtoken
    \begintestalign
         & c  \cr
    test & de \cr
    \endtestalign \cr
}

\bye
```

I have tested this idea of making `&` active when using `amsmath`, which uses `\halign` internally. We can of course change the catcode after loading the package, but I wanted to see what breaks if it is active and let to its non-active self from the start. So far, I found that `amsmath` would break because of a `\csname ... & ... \endcsname` construction: that works if `&` is an explicit alignment tab, but not when it is an active character let to an alignment tab. This can be fixed by defining `&13` to be a macro expanding to `&4` just before loading the package, then reverting to the "implicit character" definition so that alignment preambles work as expected.

```
\documentclass{article}

\def\ampMacro{&}
\let\ampImplicit&
\catcode`\&=13\relax

\let &\ampMacro
\usepackage{amsmath}
\let&\ampImplicit

\begin{document}
\begin{align}
  x^2+y^2 &= z^2 \\
  \intertext{but in general,}
  (a-b)^2 &\neq a^2 - b^2 
\end{align}
\end{document}
```