# Making a character active vs assigning it a specific catcode

Tags: tex-core, catcodes

My query arises from my answer to [Tab not as extra alignment tab](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/30348/6984) and Andrey's rather nicer version. The question at hand involved making the TAB character usable for aligning tables. I assigned it to catcode 4, alignment, whereas Andrey used catcode 13, active characters, and then `gdef`'d it to `&`.

So my general question is: supposing we want to make a new character act like `&` or `^` or whatever, *when is it best to reassign a character to a more specific catcode (like 1-4, 7, or 8), and when is it best to use the all-purpose catcode 13?*

(In the related question [Active characters let to a (non-active) character](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/11872/6984) it was mentioned that it may not be a good idea to redefine existing characters in these categories to active versions of themselves, but I'm talking here about making new characters.)

Comment: I made the character active for the sole purpose of detecting multiple tabs. Otherwise, the specific catcode would seem better and more "correct". The general rule, IMO, is _avoid active characters unless necessary_.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In Andrey's solution making `^^I` active was necessary because he wanted to catch two consecutive tabs and reduce them to one:

```
\gdef^^I{\@ifnextchar^^I{}{&}}
```

Your (amended) definition

```
\newenvironment{tabbedtabular}[1]
  {\catcode`\^^I=4 \begin{tabular}{#1}}
  {\end{tabular}}
```

will do, but it won't catch consecutive tabs, interpreting each of them as if it were `&` (neither approach solves the original problem, in my opinion, but it's another matter).

A general rule could be: assign a particular category code when you need only that, use 13 when the character must do more than a simple character with a certain category code would.

I wouldn't forget category 9 (ignored). A category 9 character stops the scanning of a control sequence name, for instance. This approach is followed in LaTeX3: in `.sty` files the space is ignored, which is very handy for avoiding the "spurious space nightmare".