# Unbalanced output routine

Tags: tex-core, output-routine

The TeX primitive `\output` behaves almost like a toks register, except in the fact that it is always surrounded by braces. For instance, after `\output={\plainoutput}`, the result of `\showthe\output` is `{\plainoutput}`, instead of what we could naively expect (no braces).

The status of the surrounded braces is a little odd. My specific problem happens when replacing the closing brace with an explicit or implicit end-group character which does not directly come from TeX's internal mechanisms.

Specifically, compiling the following example in plain TeX triggers the `! Unbalanced output routine.` error at line 6: the first case works, but not the second.

```
\output{\plainoutput \afterassignment\next \let\next}
\hbox{} \vfill \penalty -10000

\def\Next{\next}
\output{\plainoutput \afterassignment\Next \let\next}
\hbox{} \vfill \penalty -10000
```

In both cases, I redefine the output routine, then force TeX to call it (with `\penalty-10000`). I keep the normal `\plainoutput` routine, and afterwards grab the closing brace in `\next`, and put it back, either directly (`\next`), or indirectly (`\Next`). In the first, direct, case, TeX recognizes the closing brace as being from the `\output` routine, while in the second case, TeX doesn't, and gets into a state where nothing I type has any effect.

1. Why are the two situations different?
2. Assuming that I have typed the code above in the command line, is there any way to recover?

Comment: This situation makes me think of what happens when using `\futurelet` to try and grab the internal `\outer endtemplate:` token (see [discussions on this topic](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/11638/2707)). Similar investigations in the case of `\write` were discussed in [the comp.text.tex newsgroup](http://groups.google.com/group/comp.text.tex/browse_thread/thread/4841c950ab64b14f#).

Comment: Reminds me on the fact that the implicit `\relax` added by TeX when it finds `\else` while expanding tokens for a conditional, is different from the normal `\relax`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Delving through `tex.web`, I see

```
begin if (loc<>null) or 
 ((token_type<>output_text)and(token_type<>backed_up)) then
  @<Recover from an unbalanced output routine@>;
```

I don't understand when the `loc<>null` is true/false.  But the rest is easier to understand: the `token_type` tells us where the token comes from: is it inserted by TeX, is it `<to be read again>`, etc. Here, `output_text` is for tokens coming from the `\output` token parameter, which includes the closing brace, and `backed_up` is for tokens which are skipped over by `\expandafter`. I don't know why Knuth chose to  allow those two types of tokens (well, `output_text` is obvious): any other type of token makes the test true, which calls the code for an unbalanced output routine.  Thus, to close the output routine ourselves, we can simply use `\expandafter\egroup\empty`, as below:

```
\output
  {%
    \plainoutput % Plain TeX output routine
    \expandafter \egroup % End the output routine
    \let \next % Remove the closing brace inserted by TeX
  }
\hbox{} \vfill \penalty -10000
```

In case the token does not come from the right place, the following code is run

```
@ @<Recover from an unbalanced output routine@>=
begin print_err("Unbalanced output routine");
@.Unbalanced output routine@>
help2("Your sneaky output routine has problematic {'s and/or }'s.")@/
("I can't handle that very well; good luck."); error;
repeat get_token;
until loc=null;
end {loops forever if reading from a file, since |null=min_halfword<=0|}
```

After the error, TeX fetches tokens with `get_token`, until finding `null`, which presumably (according to the comment) cannot be obtained from user input, thus the user gets stuck.

Answer (score 8):

When one says

```
\toks0={\plainoutput}\showthe\toks0
```

TeX answers

```
> \plainoutput .
```

If one says after this

```
\output=\toks0
```

then `\showthe\output` gives

```
> \plainoutput .
```

If one then says `\hbox{}\penalty-10000`, then the error message

```
! Missing { inserted.
<to be read again> 
                   \shipout 
\plainoutput ->\shipout 
                        \vbox {\makeheadline \pagebody \makefootline }\advan...
<*> \hbox{}\penalty-10000
```

is issued. Now TeX is in internal vertical mode, as `\end` produces

```
`! You can't use `\end' in internal vertical mode.`
```

but typing `}` doesn't do any good, as we fall in the black hole when TeX doesn't interpret any more token.

It's interesting that TeX adds braces when the assignment to `\output` is of the form

```
\output=<general text>
```

but *not* when it's like `\output=<token register>`.

The relevant code for the addition of braces is in module 1226, where Knuth comments "For safety’s sake, we place an enclosing pair of braces around an `\output` list.", and module 1227.

An interesting module to examine is 1100, which ends with *output_group:* followed by what is in module 1026.

I realize this is not a full answer: it's only to show that it's better not to monkey with the closing brace. TeX is in a very particular type of group, when it performs the output routine and disturbing it during this task reveals to be quite dangerous.

I've also found a [discussion on `comp.text.tex`](http://groups.google.com/group/comp.text.tex/browse_frm/thread/9483b3ff5b909348/4b85cf65a4771b6b?lnk=gst&q=%2boutput%20%2btoken%20#4b85cf65a4771b6b) that seems to have points in common with this problem.

Answer (score 5):

If you trace through the code in `tex.web`, you'll find that what is important is routine 1025:

```
@ @<Fire up the user's output routine and |return|@>=
begin output_active:=true;
incr(dead_cycles);
push_nest; mode:=-vmode; prev_depth:=ignore_depth; mode_line:=-line;
begin_token_list(output_routine,output_text);
new_save_level(output_group); normal_paragraph;
scan_left_brace;
return;
end
```

As with any other case where we can have the left brace as an implicit `{`, the right brace has to be either `}` itself or an implicit `}` not hidden within a macro. So hiding `}` inside `\Next` will fail in exactly the same way as for any other situation. (You can test that the `}` is not 'special' in any other way by using `\def\Next{\egroup}`, which works fine.)

You'll also notice that the output group is actually started not by the `{` but is explicitly coded, as TeX knows that there has to be a group here. *scan_left_brace* finds an (implicit) left brace, but throws it away.

Comment: No. My first case has `\next` as a closing brace, and that is not explicit.

Comment: @BrunoLeFloch Sorry, got this wrong slightly: will edit.

Comment: @JosephWright Does `\Next`, by having being `def`ined end up in the output as a box? If this is the case then this is the cause and why the first one works and not the second example.

Comment: EDIT: my bad, I was wrong. But I think this is the only case where not hiding the implicit `}` in a macro matters. Normally, an implicit left brace can be hidden in as many macro expansions as we like (TeX uses _get\_x\_token_), and right braces are almost always explicit.

Comment: Actually, you mention "any other situation", but is there really any similar situation?

Comment: It seems that TeX arrives at the end of the file and doesn't accept any other token. I'd call this at least a quite strange behavior, if not a bug.

Comment: @egreg If that's a bug, then I'm a happy man :). 'cause you know, how many people younger than TeX found bugs in it?