# Why doesn't my redefinition of `\item` recognize that it's been passed an optional argument?

Tags: macros, lists

I wanted to redefine `\item` temporarily, but also wanted to allow it to behave as much as the *normal* `\item` should.  So, I thought by closely following the definition of `\item`, I would get the results I wanted.  However the following MWE doesn't recognize the optional argument.

```
\documentclass{article}
\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}
\begingroup
  \makeatletter
  \def\item{\@ifnextchar [\@item{\@noitemargtrue \@item[\@itemlabel]} \rule[-2ex]{0.8pt}{5ex}\endgroup}%%'
  \makeatother
\item[test]   A
\item B
\item C
\item D
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

Why is it failing?

Comment: Perhaps this will help: [When to use \LetLtxMacro?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/88001/when-to-use-letltxmacro).

Comment: @PeterGrill Given the way I was redefining `\item`, I didn't think I would need to go the `\LetLtxMacro` route.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Take a look at the definition of `\@ifnextchar` (taken from [`latex.ltx`](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/unpacked/latex.ltx)):

```
\long\def\@ifnextchar#1#2#3{%
  \let\reserved@d=#1%
  \def\reserved@a{#2}%
  \def\reserved@b{#3}%
  \futurelet\@let@token\@ifnch}
```

It stores the three arguments in three separate macros identified by `\reserved@?`. Then, it calls `\futurelet\@let@token\@ifnch`. The behaviour of `\futurelet` (as described in [Where do I find `\futurelet`'s nasty behaviour documented?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/11641/5764)) is:

> TeX also allows the construction `\futurelet\cs<token1><token2>`, which has the effect of `\let\cs = <token2><token1><token2>`.

In a simplified case, a redefinition of `\item` to have *anything* following the `\@ifnextchar` construction would cause problems, since `<token2>` will no be `[` anymore.

---

How would you get around this limitation? Don't use `\@ifnextchar` directly. Here's a naive approach using a traditional `\renewcommand` instead:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}
  \begingroup
  \makeatletter
  \let\olditem\item
  \renewcommand{\item}[1][\@empty]{%
    \ifx#1\@empty
      \olditem%
    \else
      \@item[#1] \rule[-2ex]{0.8pt}{5ex}\endgroup%
    \fi}%
  \makeatother
  \item[abc]   A
  \item B
  \item[xyz] C
  \item D
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Your code seems to be missing a `\fi`, but it nevertheless compiles.  What's happening that you don't seem to need the `\fi` to complete `\ifx`?

Comment: You are missing the `\fi` if you don't pass the optional argument to `\item`.  It seems weird that LaTeX doesn't see this error when the optional argument is present.

Comment: @A.Ellett: That was a fluke. Adding a non `\item[..]` as the first `\item` reports an error (missing `\fi`).

Answer (score 4):

As [Werner points out](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/126553), you cannot add anything 'after' `\@ifnextchar`. You also need to make sure that `\@item` is followed by a `[`, so you can't just add the rule to both branches of the `\@ifnextchar` result. At the same time, I'd avoid using a `\begingroup` outside a macro and an `\endgroup` inside one, if possible.  That leads to a solution of the form:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\pagestyle{empty}
\tracingpatches
\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}
  \let\origitem\item
    \makeatletter
  \let\orig@item\@item
  \patchcmd{\@item}{\ignorespaces}
    {%
      \rule[-2ex]{0.8pt}{5ex}%
      \let\@item\orig@item
      \ignorespaces
    }
    {}{}
  \def\item{%
    \let\item\origitem
    \@ifnextchar [%]
      \@item
      {\@noitemargtrue \@item[\@itemlabel]}%
  }
  \makeatother
\item[test] A
\item B
\item C
\item D
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

Notice that the use of `\item` will restore the original definition, as will use of `\@item`, but without a group.

Comment: I like this idea of *patching* `\@item`.  But once you've patched `\@item` there's no need for `\def\item{...}` since the contents of the definition (apart from your `\let\item\origitem`) is the definition as I found it in `latex.ltx`.

Answer (score 0):

Though not stated in the original question,  ultimately I wanted something a bit more dynamic: namely, I wanted the redefinition of `\item` to be able to persist for more than just its first occurrence.  I also wanted something that will behave *as expected* if nested within another list.

Prior to seeing @werner 's and @wright 's solutions, this is what I wound up working out:

```
\documentclass{article}
\makeatletter
\let\ae@original@item\item
\newenvironment{myenum}[1]
  {\begin{enumerate}
     \let\item\ae@original@item
     \def\ae@how@far@advanced{1}%%'
     \newif\ifae@unfinished@
     \begingroup
     \ae@unfinished@true
     \def\ae@item[##1]{%%'
       \@item[##1] \rule[-2ex]{0.8pt}{5ex}%%'
       \ifnum\ae@how@far@advanced=#1\relax
         \ae@unfinished@false\endgroup
       \fi
       \edef\ae@how@far@advanced{\number\numexpr\ae@how@far@advanced+1\relax}\ignorespaces}
     \def\item{\@ifnextchar [%%]
        \ae@item{\@noitemargtrue \ae@item[\@itemlabel]}}%%'
  }%%'
  {\ifae@unfinished@\endgroup\fi
   \end{enumerate}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{myenum}{5}
  \item A
  \item [test]   B
  \item C
    \begin{myenum}{2}
      \item Bc
      \item A
      \item C
      \item D
    \end{myenum}
  \item D
  \item E
  \item F
\end{myenum}

\end{document}
```

[image]

I suppose that `\ae@how@far@advanced` could really have been a counter.  But, I nevertheless need something since I'm counting occurrences of `\item` and not the value of `enumi` (and family), which isn't advanced when `\item[...]` is used.

I like both the solutions offered.  @wright 's solution nicely shows how to avoid my use of `\begingroup` and `\endgroup`.  But, I'd prefer not to have call another package.  @werner 's solution is very elegant in how it avoids the call to `\@ifnextchar` and manages to test for an *empty* argument.

I chose to post my own solution because I eventually saw how I was

1. misunderstanding when and what is getting expanded and
2. misunderstanding that `\@ifnextchar` was not ever going to see the next character after my macro since I'd thrown a bunch of *noise* in the way.

But I was able work out a solution with `\@ifnextchar` and to properly redirect things.