# How do I implement a string buffer in TeX?

Tags: tex-core, expansion, loops, strings

I've recently learned how to create a macro to iterate over a token sequence using `\afterassignment` and `\let` in TeX.

Currently, I'm trying to apply this to a tokenization macro (where "tokenization" means splitting a character sequence around a delimiting character/ character-sequence); that is, an algorithm `stringTokenize` which does the following:

1. Iterate over `character` in the string
2. if `character` is not the delimiter (for example, `,`): add `character` to `buffer`; if `character` is the delimiter, expand `buffer` and do something with it (that is, pass to a given macro) and clear `buffer`.

This is not as simple as I thought however, because apparently you can't expand a character which is `\let` to a command into another command (in order to create a "buffer" structure), for example,

```
\edef\buffer{\buffer\character}
```

will (after `n` iterations) expand to

```
{\character\character(...)character}
```

which is `n` times the character last `\let` to `\character`.

How do I do this?

---

Here's what I have so far:

```
\documentclass{minimal}

\makeatletter

\def\structures@stringIterate#1#2{%

    \newcount\@@index%

    \def\@@stop{§}
    \def\@@next{\afterassignment\@@each\let\@@current= }
    \def\@@each{%
      \ifx\@@current\@@stop%
         \let\@@next=\relax
      \else%
        \advance\@@index1\relax
         #2{\the\@@index}{\@@current}\let\@@next=\@@next
      \fi%
      \@@next % macro expansion must be delayed until the condition has been evaluated
    }

    \@@next#1\@@stop

}

\def\structures@stringTokenize#1#2#3{%

    \newcount\@@index
    \@@index 0\relax

    \def\@@buffer{}

    \def\@@test##1##2{%
        \ifx#2##2
            \advance\@@index 1\relax
            #3{\the\@@index}{\@@buffer}
            \def\@@buffer{} % reset the buffer
        \else
            \edef\@@buffer{\@@buffer##2} % gather character
        \fi
    }

    \structures@stringIterate{#1}{\@@test}

}

\makeatother

\begin{document}

\makeatletter

    \def\@@print#1#2{token (#1): ``#2''\par}
    \structures@stringTokenize{Humpty Dumpty sat on a wall, Humpty Dumpty had a great fall, All the King's horses and all the King's men, Couldn't put Humpty together again.}{,}{\@@print}

\makeatother

\end{document}
```

Comment: Is there a reason you are doing things this way? The natural approach to grabbing a delimited argument would be `\def\foo#1<token>{<do stuff>}`.

Comment: Also, what are the conditions we need to take account of: can we use e-TeX, do you want an expandable iterator, ...?

Comment: Also, you seem to be looking for `\futurelet`!

Comment: @JosephWright No other real reason than learning the TeX way of things. The conditions would be *as core TeX as possible*. Can you expand on the use of `\futurelet` in this context?

Comment: BTW, what you get out of this process is a series of tokens, not a string. In TeX terms, a 'string' is a series of tokens of category code 12, with the exception of spaces which have category code 10.

Comment: @JosephWright Yes, that's exactly the problem. The result of my code is a series of tokens `\character\character(...)\character` where the respective string would be `Hu(...).`. Since `\character` will (correctly) be assigned to the last character reached within the loop, the result is `n` times the expansion of `\character` (which is not the desired result).

Comment: BTW, there are various issues with your code not related to the matter in hand. You shouldn't have blank lines in your definitions (mentioned in comments on http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/184438/how-do-you-define-macros-to-toggle-a-character-active-and-define-a-macro-for-it), you shouldn't have `\newcount\@@index` twice: really should be _outside_ your macros, and you need to watch your line ends (some important `%` missing).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The usual approach to grabbing tokens with a delimiter in TeX would be something like

```
\catcode`\@=11 %

\def\grabargs#1#2#3{%
  \def\grabargs@aux##1#2{%
    \ifx\relax##1\relax%
    \else
      #3{##1}\par
      \expandafter\grabargs@aux
    \fi
  }%
  \grabargs@aux#1#2\relax#2
}
\def\print#1{`{\tt #1}'}
\catcode`\@=12 %

\grabargs
  {Humpty Dumpty sat on a wall, Humpty Dumpty had a great fall, All the King's horses and all the King's men, Couldn't put Humpty together again.}
  {,}
  {\print}

\bye
```

where depending how complex things need to be we can use a more fancy approach to stopping the loop.

What you can't do is use `\let` here (at least in any particularly easy way): this creates *implicit* tokens which as you've found can be expanded in, for example, `\edef`. What you might be looking to do is pick up space tokens: they are tricky to grab as a normal argument (`#1`), so you might use `\futurelet` in something like

```
\catcode`\@=11 %

\newcount\mycount
\def\grabargs#1#2#3{%
  \def\grabbed@tokens{}%
  \mycount\z@
  \def\grabargs@auxii{%
    \ifx\grab@token#2%
      \grabargs@auxiv
      \def\grabbed@tokens{}%
      \expandafter\grabargs@auxv
    \else
      \ifx\grab@token\@sptoken
        \expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\grabargs@space
      \else
        \ifx\grab@token\relax
        \else
          \expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter
            \expandafter\expandafter\grabargs@auxiii
        \fi
      \fi
    \fi
  }%
  \def\grabargs@auxiv{%
    #3{\the\mycount}\grabbed@tokens
    \mycount\z@
  }%
  \grabargs@auxi#1#2\relax
}
\def\grabargs@auxi{%
  \futurelet\grab@token\grabargs@auxii
}
\def\grabargs@auxiii#1{%
  \edef\grabbed@tokens{%
    \grabbed@tokens
    #1%
  }%
  \advance\mycount\@ne
  \grabargs@auxi
}
\def\grabargs@auxv#1{\grabargs@auxi}
\expandafter\def\expandafter\grabargs@space\space{%
  \grabargs@auxiii\space
}
\def\:{\let\@sptoken= } \:  %
\def\print#1#2{Tokens: #1 `{\tt #2}'\par}
\catcode`\@=12 %

\grabargs
  {Humpty Dumpty sat on a wall, Humpty Dumpty had a great fall, All the King's horses and all the King's men, Couldn't put Humpty together again.}
  {,}
  {\print}

\bye
```

The idea here is that `\futurelet` is very similar to your `\afterassignment\@@each\let\@@current=` except it *doesn't* remove the token from the input stream. We grab a token using `\futurelet` then can examine it. If it's the marker, we can print the current grabbed tokens (and count), then loop. If it's the end marker, we stop, and if it's a 'normal' token we can grab the argument and store. If it's a space, we do a special version of the 'grab' macro which will handle a space. What I've not added in the above is code to deal with brace groups: that can be done but the approach depends on what you want to do about such things.

---

Note that in both of the above implementations we are storing tokens, which could mean issues with category code 6 tokens (usually `#`) and how you want to manage line breaks, *etc.* This can all be sorted out, but without a tighter spec I'm leaving it alone. Also, note that it's easy to get caught out by `\futurelet` in an `\halign`: see for example [Where do I find \futurelet's nasty behaviour documented?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/11638/where-do-i-find-futurelets-nasty-behaviour-documented).

Comment: `\futurelet` will always expand the second token it receives, right? That's undesirable in this case, because I want to leave the decision whether or not to print the tokenized sub-string to the document to the macro passed as the third argument to `structures@stringTokenize`. Probably should have stated that more clearly. Sorry!

Comment: @FK82 No, `\futurelet` does an assignment to the its first argument then executes its second argument (it's one of the most complex primitives in TeX!). The second arg of `\futurelet` is much like your `\@@each` in the question. As your demo uses a printing operation I have too: change `\print` to a no-op to see this.

Comment: @FK82 Also, as I've commented on the question you _don't_ have a string here (and it's already tokenized): you've got a token list.

Comment: Where do I not have a string?

Comment: @FK82 Everywhere: you've not detokenized anything. In TeX we deal with tokens which have category codes: for example `a` is usually a 'letter' (catcode 11) while `#` is a 'macro parameter' (catcode 6) and `{` is an 'open group' token (catcode 1). Note that something like `\relax` is one token, again assume 'usual' circumstances. TeX 'strings' are generated by for example `\meaning` or `\string`: they have category code 12 ('other') for all characters except for " " (space) which have category code 10 ('space').

Comment: Yeah, well, this amounts to saying there are no strings because everything is a token (of differing categories).

Comment: @FK82 Not exactly: one can treat things without using catcode (see for example `\if` _versus_ `\ifx`). I'm just trying to get across that in TeX a 'string' is a particular thing which is not the same as a 'token list', and it's important to understand the difference.

Comment: I see, seems like I have to learn a bit more about basic concepts of TeX.