# How to make the frame dashed?

Tags: beamer, framed

I am using `\begin{framed} ... \end{framed}` in my presentation, does anyone know how to make the frame **dashed**?

Comment: Looking at the documentation of `framed`, this doesn't seem to be a feature natively supported by the package.

Comment: There actually is a near-duplicate for this question: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/11291/dashed-box-environment

Answer (score 11):

Here a solution with `mdframed`

```
\documentclass[english]{beamer}
\usepackage[style=1]{mdframed}[2011/08/22]
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\begin{mdframed}[tikzsetting={draw=blue,dashed,line width=2pt,dash pattern = on 10pt off 3pt},linecolor=yellow,backgroundcolor=yellow,outerlinewidth=1pt]
Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text 
\end{mdframed}

\begin{mdframed}[tikzsetting={draw=blue,dashed,line width=2pt,dash pattern = on 10pt off 3pt},linecolor=yellow,backgroundcolor=yellow,outerlinewidth=1pt]
Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text 
Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text 
Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text 
Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text 
\end{mdframed}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Sorry for the advertising.

[image]

EDIT: You can define the special environment in the header with the following code:

```
\newmdenv[tikzsetting={draw=blue,dashed,line width=2pt,dash pattern = on 10pt off 3pt},%
linecolor=yellow,backgroundcolor=yellow,outerlinewidth=1pt]{beamerframe}
```

Now you can use the environment as usual.

```
\begin{beamerframe}
Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text 
\end{beamerframe}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply... It says `File mdframed.sty not found`...

Comment: What do you use? TexLive or MikTeX and which version do you have?

Comment: If I type `latex -version` in a terminal, it returns `TeX Live 2009/Debian`. And I am using Emacs and LaTeX...

Comment: THe example works only with Texlive 2011 and the newest version of `mdframed`. For `beamer` you can use a solution of the threat which is linked by doncherry in the comment above.