# How to surround text or values with dashed box within paragraph?

Tags: tikz-pgf, fbox

I need to put text and values inside a dashed box for focus purposes.
within a paragraph, I have tested this [Dashed box environment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/11291/dashed-box-environment) it's not my need

I want it like this way

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Dashed box environment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/11291/dashed-box-environment)

Comment: @bmv my SIr I said in a paragraph, I have already tried that  Dashed box environment

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do it with TikZ:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}

\newcommand\dboxed[1]{\tikz [baseline=(boxed word.base)] \node (boxed word) [draw, rectangle, dashed, line cap=round] {#1};}

\begin{document}

This is a \dboxed{Test} sentence.

\end{document}
```

[image: output of the mwe]

Answer (score 3):

Another solution based in [Thomas F. Sturm](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/166232/1952) answer to [Dashed box environment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/11291/dashed-box-environment). I've just adapted his solution into a `tcbox`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}

\newtcbox{\dbox}[1][]{
    on line,
    enhanced,
    frame hidden,
    interior hidden,
    sharp corners,
    size=small,
    borderline={0.4pt}{0pt}{dashed},
    #1
}

\begin{document}

This is a \dbox{test} with \dbox{tcolorbox}.
\end{document}
```

[image]